# import cannot be resolved for ZXing java project

Tags: java, eclipse, zxing

I'm trying to use ZXing with eclipse

I've tried importing the jars I found [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/)

[image: ZXingImport]

Eclipse still can't seem to find these imports

```
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
```

Which is odd because `import com.google.zxing.*;` works fine

Maybe these are no longer part of the JAR?

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your lib is empty,white package means no class file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the wrong `jar` file

I now use `zxing_core.jar`

Not sure what those others were supposed to be...

Answer (score -1):

ADD zxing_core dependency for springboot.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @sav is not using maven, but importing the jars into his eclipse project. Your answer doesn't work for him.

Comment: Add jar file instead of dependency